# Why is Entity Framework's migrations Configuration.cs file located and executed automatically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a C# project where I'm using Entity Framework 6.1. I have a few migration files and a `Configuration.cs` file within the same folder. `Configuration.cs` contains the following class:

```
namespace SNS.Database.Migrations
{
    public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SNSContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(SNSContext context)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If I understand Entity Framework correctly, the `Seed` method is supposed to be executed after a new database migration file has been applied. Furthermore, to configure this, it's done with the following call:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SNSContext, Configuration>());
```

That works fine. However, the `Seed` method does always get called, even if I haven't made the `SetInitializer` call.

So my question is, what tells Entity Framework to run `Configuration.cs`, and why does it always execute the `Seed` method?

I have already checked in my `App.config` file, and it doesn't specify [codeConfigurationType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_3).